# What is the 'risky' in Emacs?

Tags: macos, emacs

I'd like to start Emacs on Mac OS X.

When I run 'emacs' comamnd in terminal, I got the error;

```
signal(error ("Unknown keyword :risky"))
  error("Unknown keyword %s" :risky)
  custom-handle-keyword(package-load-list :risky t custom-variable)
...
..
```

What is the 'risky'?

I just install 'Starter Kit'.

How I solve this problem?

===== UPDATE

This error only occure in Built-in Emacs on Mac OSX Terminal.

**In GUI Emacs(GNU), It works.**

Here is full trace of error.

```
Debugger entered--Lisp error: (error "Cannot return from the debugger in an error")
  signal(error ("Unknown keyword :risky"))
  error("Unknown keyword %s" :risky)
  custom-handle-keyword(package-load-list :risky t custom-variable)
  custom-declare-variable(package-load-list (quote (all)) "List of packages for `package-initialize' to load.\nEach el$
  (defcustom package-load-list (quote (all)) "List of packages for `package-initialize' to load.\nEach element in this$
  eval-buffer(#> nil "/Users/rushcut/.emacs.d/package.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 9123
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/rushcut/.emacs.d/package.el" "/Users/rushcut/.emacs.d/package.el" nil t)
  require(package)
  eval-buffer(# nil "/Users/rushcut/.emacs.d/init.el" nil t)  ; Reading at buffer position 1099
  load-with-code-conversion("/Users/rushcut/.emacs.d/init.el" "/Users/rushcut/.emacs.d/init.el" t t)
  load("/Users/rushcut/.emacs.d/init" t t)
  #[nil "^H\205\276^@   \306=\203^Q^@\307^H\310Q\202A^@ \311=\2033^@\312\307\313\314#\203#^@\315\202A^@\312\307\313\31$
  command-line()
  normal-top-level()
```

===== FINALLY

**Install emacs 23.2.**

**Everything works fine.**

Comment: If this happens before you do anything, launch emacs with the --debug-init option.  That should tell you where the error is occuring.

Comment: I had the same problem, installed emacs with homebrew, removed `/usr/bin/emacs` (which was version 22 anyway). Seemed to fix it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Remove the starter kit, start fresh.

As [harpo](https://stackoverflow.com/users/4525/harpo) commented, to debug your actual problem, try starting Emacs with `--debug-init`, which should provide a stack trace showing what line caused the problem.

But really, get rid of the starter kit.

If you want to start using Emacs, check out [all the other questions folks have asked about beginning Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bemacs%5D+beginner) and try some of the tips for beginners folks have already given.  Of particular interest is a question about [starting with Ergo Emacs](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3323630/should-i-start-out-learning-emacs-with-ergoemacs), which is essentially the same thing as starting off with the Starter Kit.

UPDATE

From your stack trace, it looks as though the version of `custom` that the starter kit expects is newer than the version shipped with the Emacs you're using on the Mac.  The `risky` is a keyword for `defcustom`, which was added in Emacs 23.1 (see [NEWS.23.1](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/NEWS.23.1)).  So, either upgrade your Mac's Emacs, download a newer version of custom (may not be possible at this point), or remove the starter kit by commenting out `(require 'package)` in your `.init.el`.